# Exceptionally long computing time for recursive implementation of quicksort

Tags: c#, recursion, quicksort

I tried to implement a quicksort algorithm but it seems to have some bad behaviour. It does sort an array of elements but it takes too much time, to be exact it takes so much time for about 165 elements it hasn't finished once(ran it a couple of minutes). I tried to debug and realized that it might take to many iterations to finish, still producing the right output. The code is written within a class which inherits List and should be programmed recursively. Am I doing it wrong? I am feeling like the procedure takes too many iterations. I mean, it is calls **QUICK**sort.

This is the code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collection.Generic;

  public class PersonList : List<Person>{ 
       public void quickSort(int start, int end){
            if(start < end){
                 int pivot = partition(start, end);
                 if(pivot > 1){
                      quickSort(start, end -1);
                 }
                 if(pivot + 1 < end){
                      quickSort(pivot + 1, end);
                 }
            }
       }




       public int partition(int start, int end){
            Person per = new Person();
            int tmp = this[start].ID;
            while(true){
                 while(this[start].ID < tmp){
                      start++;
                 }
                 while(this[end].ID > tmp){
                      end--;
                 }
                 if(start < end){
                      if(this[start].ID == this[end].ID){
                           return end;
                      } else{
                           per = this[start];
                           this[start] = this[end];
                           this[end] = per;
                      }
                 } else{
                      return end;
                 }
            }
       }          
 }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are building your own rather than using an existing sort algorithm?

Comment: `if(pivot > 1){
                      quickSort(start, end -1);
                 }` This doesn't seem right.

Comment: If it doesn't seem right, what does?

Comment: `(start, pivot)` ... ? But I'm still going through the code ... That was just my immediate impression.

Comment: Also, `Person per = new Person();` you are creating a new Person object here. It's not needed. You only need the local var. You set it to this[start] anyway.

Comment: BTW: If this is some sort of homework, it is well-received on SO to state so in the question.

Comment: It is no homework, more like a personal aproach to learn.

Comment: If this is a personal approach to learn, take it as a chance to learn how to use a profiler. It's a way underestimated skill for developers.

Comment: I think you can obtain an evaluation license for Resharper ultimate for 14 days. This includes dotTrace, a great profiler.

Comment: It would be nice if we were looking at the actual code. Hint - C# is a case sensitive language, so what you've shown us here doesn't compile. So how are we even to know how close this is to what you're actually testing?

Comment: This is the actual code and it does compile for me. What is missing?

Comment: Maybe you can tell me wich line you are refering to and what is wrong with it.

Comment: I changed it more than an hour ago

Comment: [Cross-posted and closed at Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/177821/52915)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the following line

```
quickSort(start, end -1);
```

QuickSort is a divide and conquer algorithm which divides the dataset it operates on to smaller chunks and recursively operates on the smaller chunks (and then devides those). What you did here is, that you called QuickSort not on the lower "half" of your data set (what is how it's supposed to work), but on the data set reduced by the topmost item. Because of this line the recursion operates on a way larger dataset than it's supposed to do and hence takes longer.

The correct line to operate on the reduced data set would be

```
quickSort(start, pivot)
```

Since the data points are presorted relative to the pivot element you can divide your data set to the chunks lower and higher than the pivot element. Hence I believe even

```
quickSort(start, pivot - 1)
```

would suffice.

**Edit**

According to the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Pseudocode) (pseudocode should be readable, although it's in german) the code should look more like

```
private int Partition(int start, int end)
{
    var pivot = end;

    var i = start;
    var j = end - 1;

    int tmp = this[pivot].ID;

    do
    {
        while (this[i].ID < tmp && i < end)
        {
            i++;
        }

        while (this[j].ID > tmp && j > start)
        {
            j--;
        }

        if (i < j)
        {
            Swap(i, j);
        }
    }
    while (i < j);


    if (this[i].ID > tmp)
    {
        Swap(i, pivot);
    }

    return i;
}
```

We have to use separate loop variables, since they are checked against `start` and `end` and we'd lose this information if `start` and `end` themselves changed.

Comment: Changing to `quickSort(start,pivot)` gives me an overflow exception at the line `int tmp = this[start].ID;`

Comment: The list contains 165 elements

Comment: I've just ran it for 10k list elements and it did not give me an overflow exception. How is `Person` defined?

Comment: What's the value of  `start` when the exception occurs?

Comment: Only the class with a property for "ID" like `public int ID {get;set;}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156639/discussion-between-paul-kertscher-and-thomas).